# NodeJS/Express PUT request failing with: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am trying to build a service (residing on a different subdomain than the site calling it) with NodeJS/Express.

My GET and POST methods work fine, but I am having a bit of trouble with the PUT.

I have attempted to implement *corser* but I am still getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://services.example.org/jobs/_id/5503bb957e4eacd821b5c046. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.org' is therefore not allowed access.

Below is my *corser* implementation.  I understand that some of this might be redundant or unnecessary.   I am just trying to find the magic setting to make the PUT request complete successfully.

```
app.use(corser.create({
    simpleRequestHeaders: corser.simpleRequestHeaders.concat(["PUT"]),
    simpleRequestHeaders: corser.simpleRequestHeaders.concat(["OPTIONS"]),
    simpleResponseHeaders: corser.simpleResponseHeaders.concat(["PUT"]),
    simpleResponseHeaders: corser.simpleResponseHeaders.concat(["OPTIONS"]),
    requestHeaders: corser.simpleRequestHeaders.concat(["X-Requested-With"])
}));
app.all('*', function(request, response, next) {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got in touch with the lead developer of *corser* and found them very helpful.

This was the magic bullet that got me past my CORS issues.

```
var corser = require('corser');
```

---

```
// Configure CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) Headers 
app.use(corser.create({
    methods: corser.simpleMethods.concat(["PUT"]),
    requestHeaders: corser.simpleRequestHeaders.concat(["X-Requested-With"])
}));
app.all('*', function(request, response, next) {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,DELETE');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});
```

Hopefully this will prove useful to anyone who has similar issues in the future.